# Can someone help me with my loop code?

Tags: java

A real estate office handles 50 apartment units. When the rent is $600 per month, all the units are occupied. However, for each $40 increase in rent,one unit becomes vacant. Each occupied unit requires an average of $27 permonth for maintenance. How many units should be rented to maximize the profit

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ChapterFiveHomework
{
   static Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);

   public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
   {

   int units;
   double rent;
   double startRent;
   double rentInc;
   double maintenance;
   double totalMaintenance;
   double earnings;
   double earnings2;

   System.out.println("Enter the number of appartment units.");
   units = console.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Enter the rent ammount when all units are occupied.");
   rent = console.nextDouble();

   System.out.println("Enter the increase in rent that results in a vacant"
                                                              +" unit.");
   rentInc = console.nextDouble();

   System.out.println("Enter the ammount to maintain a rented unit.");
   maintenance = console.nextDouble();

   earnings2 = (units-1)*(rent+rentInc)-maintenance*(units-1);
   earnings = units*rent-maintenance*units;

   do
   {
      units--;
      rent = rent+rentInc;
      earnings = (units--)*(rent+rentInc)-(maintenance*(units--));
   }
   while (earnings > earnings2);

   System.out.println("Number of units to rent:" + (units));
   System.out.printf("Ammount to charge for rent: %.2f", rent);

   }
}
```

Comment: What is the nature of your problem?

Comment: I feel like this is homework.

Comment: Also has nothing to do with unit testing.

Comment: Ryen: it is homework, and I just can't get it to match the answer that I got by doing all the math by hand

Comment: @wadelom42 - You need to use an `@` in front of the user name to message them. Also, you need to clearly show what is doing wrong, what the correct answer is, and what you need your code to do to get the right answer.

Comment: @Enigmativity my bad. This is my first time using this site. The number of units that it outputs is correct: 32, but the rent should end up being 1320, while it ends up outputting 840.  I guess I just need to fix something with the rent increase, but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Several *immediate* problems I see here:

```
do
{
    units--;
    rent = rent+rentInc;
    earnings = (units--)*(rent+rentInc)-(maintenance*(units--));
}
while (earnings > earnings2);
```

First, you're doing the first calculation based on already vacating an apartment. That means you're not examining the possibility that $600 rent is the best option.

Secondly, you're decrementing `units` *three times* each time through that loop.

Thirdly, you're terminating the loop where the earnings is no longer rising. While it doesn't matter in *this* particular case, you should be aware of the problem of local maxima.

For example, if the figures went `1, 2, 3, 2, 9999`, your loop would stop when it found the second `2` rather than carrying on to the `9999`.

---

Here's the simplest way to do it, in my opinion. Basically, you have a loop starting with $600 rent. Though it could be argued that $639 would be the correct starting point since only a *$40* increase would result in "losing" the first apartment, I'll keep it at $600 for simplicity. The loop also starts with full occupancy.

Each time through the loop, you work out the profit based on your formula, then increase the rent by $40 and decrease the occupancy by one until the occupancy reaches zero.

You're actually *very* close to that, other than the issues I mentioned above, so it will hopefully be relatively easy to change the loop you have to be the equivalent to the pseudo-code below:

```
# Configurable items.
rentbase = 600
rentincr = 40
numapts  = 50
expsper = 27

maxprofit = -1
maxoccupancy = -1
maxrentper = -1

rentper = rentbase
occupancy = 50
while occupancy > 0:
    income = rentper * occupancy
    expense = expsper * occupancy
    profit = income - expense

    print occupancy, rentper, profit
    if maxprofit < profit:
        maxprofit = profit
        maxoccupancy = occupancy
        maxrentper = rentper

    rentper = rentper + rentincr
    occupancy = occupancy - 1

print "==="
print maxoccupancy, maxrentper, maxprofit
```

Using that method, the correct answer appears to be $1,320 rent for 32 apartments, giving $41,376 profit.